# Applying a function when using ReplaceAll

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

For example, I have a list
`m={{1,-1,3},{-2,1,-3},{-2,3,3}}` and a function `f[x_]=-x^2`.

What I want to do is to apply `f` only to the negative values in `m`.

So, the outcome should be `m1={{1,-1,3},{-4,1,-9},{-4,3,3}}`.

How can I do this? I tried

`m/. _?Negative ->-#^2`.... but it doesn't work properly...

Comment: Name the pattern and use the pattern's name: `m /. x_?Negative :> -x^2` or `m /. x_?Negative :> f[x]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the outcome should be m1={{1,-1,3},{-4,1,-9},{-4,3,3}}.

```
ClearAll[f,x];
m = {{1, -1, 3}, {-2, 1, -3}, {-2, 3, 3}};
f[x_] := -x^2
Map[If[# < 0, f[#], #] &, m, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to use `ReplaceAll`

```
 m /. (x_ /; x < 0) :> f[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to consider:

```
Attributes[f] = Listable;

f[x_?Negative] := -x^2
f[else_] := else

m = {{1, -1, 3}, {-2, 1, -3}, {-2, 3, 3}};

f[m]
```

> ```
> {{1, -1, 3}, {-4, 1, -9}, {-4, 3, 3}}
> ```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? When I leave out the f[else_], it does not work. What exactly is it doing? Thanks.

Comment: @Moo -  `f[else_] := else` causes any input other than a negative number to be return unchanged.